# Process Resident Set Size and huge pages

Tags: java, linux, huge-pages

Does Process Resident Set Size (RSS) accounts for pages mapped as huge pages?
For example on Centos 7 configured as (Transparent Huge Pages disabled, huge pages pool configured as min: 0, max 200000):

```
[root@p]# cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
always madvise [never]
[root@p]# cat /proc/sys/vm/nr_overcommit_hugepages 
200000
[root@p]# cat /proc/sys/vm/nr_hugepages
0
```

Will the process created as:

Hello.java:

```
import javax.net.*;

class Hello {
   public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
       System.out.println("Hello!");
       Thread.sleep(1000000);
   }
```

}

```
javac Hello.java

java -XX:+UseLargePages -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -Xmx120000m -Xms120000m Hello
```

cause the RSS column in the displayed result of:

```
ps axu |grep java
```

to show around 120Gb?

What I am trying to ultimately figure out here is if java does pre-touch huge pages in my configuration or something else is wrong.

Comment: To my knowledge, huge pages are not counted in RSS "due to historical reasons". You can differentiate between touched and untouched pages by issuing `cat /proc/meminfo  | grep HugePages_`. If pages are untouched, then both Total and Free will be identically large. If pages are touched, then Total will be large and Free will be zero.

Comment: Or even better, you can find memory region in `/proc/<pid>/smaps`. If it is touched, its Private_Hugetlb field will be equal to Size.